# Bundled extras do not seem to be passing correctly with my Intent

Tags: android

I'm attempting to pass a team name, and the number of penalties that team have received via an intent. The team name is successfully bundled and retrieved (to a textView) however when I try to do the same thing with the total penalties, it doesn't work.

**Creating the intent and starting the activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Timing.this, Results.class);
intent.putExtra("totalpenalties", totalpenalties); 
intent.putExtra("teamname", intentExtras.getString("teamname")); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**Retrieving the bundled extras in the new activity**

```
Bundle intentExtras;  
int totalPenalties; 

intentExtras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

tvTeamNameDisplay.setText(intentExtras.getString("teamname"));
totalPenalties = intentExtras.getInt("totalpenalties"); 
tvTotalPenalties.setText(String.format("%d",totalPenalties));
```

The bundled team name displays correctly, however the totalPenalties does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really strange. Have you tryed to put a Log before adding the totalpenalties to the bundle in order to check what do you enter into the intent?

Is totalpenalties an int?

Try to add some log and post them. If teamname is passed in the right way there is no reason for not working with others extras.

Comment: "totalpenalties" was mistakenly declared as a long in the other class, so retrieving it as an integer obviously did not work ;) 

Sorry, I noticed that right as I posted (always the way, huh? ages trying to debug and as soon as you ask for help you figure out the problem!) Thanks :)